# Typescript: Union function parameter typeguarding

Tags: typescript

I want to search widgets by color or series (at least one is required). This doesn't compile:

```js
export function widgets(params: {colorId: number} | {seriesId: number}) {
  if (params.colorId){
    // Search widgets by color
  } else {
    // Search widgets by series
  }
}
```

Error: `Property 'colorId' does not exist on type '{ colorId: number; } | { seriesId: number; }'.`

I know I can make it work this way:

```js
type ColorId = { colorId: number };
function isColorId(params: any): params is ColorId {
  return typeof params.colorId === "number";
}
export function widgets(params: { colorId: number } | { seriesId: number }) {
  if (isColorId(params)) {
    // Search widgets by color
  } else {
    // Search widgets by series
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is a solution with less boilerplate. It seems like there should be something more elegant for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest way to narrow the type in this case is to use an `in` type guard:

```
export function widgets(params: {colorId: number} | {seriesId: number}) {
  if ('colorId' in params) {
    params.colorId
    // Search widgets by color
  } else {
    params.seriesId
    // Search widgets by series
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwO6YAmA5sDAM4AUYAhlDQLbkBccA3mhADbQCShrFEgYAjYFAC+cAD7ty4zMHL9BwsZICU7ALAAoOHEwI4lAOSceUfqcO5a9JlrZ6DB+43IA6C30IvXAPQBcADKwHRoABb4RKQUcCIAnnA+UP5SwFzyOvqu7kye8lCKyn65BkGh4VBRMSRk5AnJRSXpehJAA)

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be something like that.

Comment: Thank you!!! Obviously I couldn't destructure in the function parameter